# Will this mix of Shimano 10 speed components work together?

Tags: shimano, 1x10

My goal is to cobble together a 1x10 groupset using some Shimano 105 5700 shifters.

From what I have read, I think that these components will work together, but I want to be sure before purchasing:

- Shimano 105 5700 10 speed shifters
- Shimano GRX RD-RX400 10 speed rear derailleur
- Shimano Deore HG50 10 speed cassette 11-36
- Shimano Deore T610 10 speed rear hub

I will be in a 1x configuration, so no front mech is required.

Will this mix of Shimano 10 speed components work together?

Comment: You've been given good answers below. You might also consider just getting a Microshift Advent 9 RD and an 11-42 10 speed cassette. Better range and you still have a clutch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You’ll need a **9** speed mountain bike rear derailleur because they use the same cable pull ratio as 10 speed road shifters (except for the Tiagra 4700).

I’m using 105 5700 brifters with a 9 speed SLX rear derailleur, 10 speed 11–34 Deore cassette and 10 speed chain. Works nicely. Shifting maybe requires a bit more force and is maybe a tad less snappy. Could just be because of the larger gear steps compared to the 12–30 cassette and 105 derailleur I had before. All 10 gears shift without any issues. Combined with a 33 teeth small chainring it gives me better than 1:1 gear ratio for travelling with luggage.

Comment: This is true, but your answer would be improved by explaining why this combination works together, i.e both 9 speed MTB  and 10 speed road use the classic 1:1.7 actuation ratio.

Comment: Interesting! do you have access to all 10 speeds?

Comment: Are there issues using a 10 speed chain in a 9 speed RD?

Comment: I’ve updated the answer. I’ve used this setup for thousands of kilometers and it’s working nicely.

Comment: You can also use a 10-speed MTB derailleur with a cable pull conversion device like Wolf Tooth's Tanpan

Answer (score 9):

Sorry no, the 105 shifters and GRX derailleur will not work together.

Older Shimano 10 speed groupsets use the 'classic' 1:1.7 actuation ratio (length cable pulled / lateral cage movement). 11 speed groups required a different ratio to work properly. The newer 10 speed groups - Tiagra 4700 and GRX 400 series - both use the same ratio as the 11 speed groups, and are therefore not compatible with the older 10 speed groups.

Shimano publishes extensive specifications an compatibility information for their products. The latest compatibility information is here: https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com. If you look at road rear drivetrain compatibility you see that the GRX RX400 derailleur only works with Tiagra 47xx, 'Non series' RS405 and GRX RX400 shifters.

You can see that the HG50 cassette is explicitly compatible with the RX400 derailleur.

Comment: Is the old Shimano 105 5701 medium-cage rear derailleur compatable with an appropriately size MTB cassette (up to 32t I believe)?

Answer (score 7):

Can confirm that 5700 shifters and GRX RD-RX400 don't work together.

Sorry, I can't 'comment' yet, but I can confirm after unwittingly trying this myself - and leading to further research on the subject - that 5700 shifters do not play nicely with the GRX RD-RX400.  Because of the different pull, it never stays in gear no matter how you try to adjust/curse at it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Actually, this is a perfect serviceable answer; no need to apologize for it.